# What type-hint contains both list and tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

I have a function that can accept as input any variable that can be indexed, such as a list or a tuple. How do I indicate this in the type-hint of the function?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Your method is accepting a [*sequence*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence), so use [`typing.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence). That's a generic, so you can specify what type of object(s) the sequence must contain:

```
from typing import Sequence

def foo(bar: Sequence[int]):
    # bar is a sequence of integers
```

Quoting the [Python glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence):

> An iterable which supports efficient element access using integer indices via the `__getitem__()` special method and defines a `__len__()` method that returns the length of the sequence. Some built-in sequence types are `list`, `str`, `tuple`, and `bytes`.

Comment: Must I specify the type of items in the sequence, or can I just say "bar: sequence" ?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi: not specifying a contained type is allowed; the default is `Any`, so `bar: Sequence` and `bar: Sequence[Any]` are equivalent.

Comment: Is there a type which contains `list` and `tuple` but not `str` and `bytes`? Or should one just use `Union[list, tuple]` for such cases?

Comment: @Nathan: yes, you'd have to be explicit about the specific types. You can't spell *this should be a sequence, but not these specific sequence types*.

Comment: @Nathan: note, however, that `str` is a `Sequence[str]` type, and wouldn't be acceptable if `Sequence[int]` is required. Vice-versa, `bytes` is a `Sequence[int]` type, and would be rejected if you tried to use it with a function that requires `Sequence[str]`. Both are immutable types, so `MutableSequence[int]` or `MutableSequence[str]` would not accept either (but `bytearray` would be acceptable for `MutableSequence[int]`).

Comment: It's the first part that got me - `str` is a `Sequence[str]`. I had a`Sequence[str]` parameter to a function and was surprised that typing didn't care about passing a `str` to it, but it makes sense once you think about it. I just use `Union[List[str], Tuple[str, ...]]` now; thanks!