# Python type-hinting, indexable object

Tags: python, type-hinting

My function needs to accept an object, from which data can be extracted by index, viz. a `List` or an instance with defined `__getitem__` method.

Which type can I use for type hinting this argument?

Update:
As I understand there are presently no such type, I tried to make one myself:

```py
class IndexableContainer(Generic[int, ReturnType]):
    def __getitem__(self, key: int) -> ReturnType:
        ...
```

But I get the following error:

```sh
  File "indexable_container.py", line 22, in IndexableContainer
    class IndexableContainer(Generic[int, ReturnType]):
  File ".../lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 682, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwds)
  File ".../lib/python3.6/typing.py", line 1112, in __getitem__
    "Parameters to Generic[...] must all be type variables")
TypeError: Parameters to Generic[...] must all be type variables
```

How should I do it?

Comment: If it is an iterable then you can use this typehint: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Iterable
If not then you should create your own typehint class.

Comment: Unfortunately, it has to be indexable, not iterable. How can I create my own typehinting class?

Comment: You can find an example about this here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic

Comment: Sorry, that example is incomplete and I couldn't make it work. Do you have a better one?

Comment: You only have to hint the KeyType and the ValueType. E.g. If the key can be only a string then use `str`.

Comment: I need the KeyType to be `int`, but it is not allowing me to do that. See the error I added.

Comment: You didnt specify ReturnType, if every type is allowed then use Any, if specific types are allowed, then create a TypeVar(see docs).

Comment: Sorry, ReturnType is specified above that, I forgot to include it. But that is not the problem. The problem is that I can't use `int` as input for `Generic`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several different ways you can do this.

If you're ok with using only custom classes (that you can write) as indexable containers, all you need to do is to adapt your code and remove that 'int' type parameter:

```
class IndexableContainer(Generic[ReturnType]):
    def __getitem__(self, key: int) -> ReturnType:
        ...

class MyCustomContainer(IndexableContainer[ReturnType]):
    def __getitem__(self, key: int) -> ReturnType:
        # Implementation here

def requires_indexable_container(container: IndexableContainer[ReturnType]) -> ReturnType:
    # Code using container here
```

The issue is, of course, that if you wanted to pass in a plain old list into the function, you wouldn't be able to do so since list doesn't subclass your custom type.

We could maybe special-case certain inputs via clever use of the `@overload` decorator and unions, but there's a second, albeit experimental, way of doing this known as [Protocols](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/class_basics.html#simple-user-defined-protocols).

Protocols basically let you express "duck typing" in a sane way using type hints: the basic idea is that we can tweak IndexableContainer to become a protocol. Now, any object that implements the `__getitem__` method with the appropriate signature is counted as a valid IndexableContainer, whether or not they subclass that type or not.

The only caveat is that Protocols are currently experimental and (afaik) only supported by mypy. The plan is to eventually add protocols to the general Python ecosystem -- see [PEP 544](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) for the specific proposal -- but I haven't kept track of the discussion/don't know what the status of that is.

In any case, to use protocols, install the `typing_extensions` module using pip. Then, you can do the following:

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol

# ...snip...


class IndexableContainer(Protocol, Generic[ReturnType]):
    def __getitem__(self, key: int) -> ReturnType:
        ...

def requires_indexable_container_of_str(container: IndexableContainer[str]) -> None:
    print(container[0] + "a")

a = ["a", "b", "c"]
b = {0: "foo", 2: "bar"}
c = "abc"
d = [1, 2, 3]

# Type-checks
requires_indexable_container_of_str(a)
requires_indexable_container_of_str(b)
requires_indexable_container_of_str(c)

# Doesn't type-check
requires_indexable_container_of_str(d)
```

Comment: As a supplement, after Python 3.8, `Protocol` has been added to the `typing`, and the `Protocol` class can be generic. Therefore, `(Protocol, Generic[ReturnType])` in the answer can be rewritten as `(Protocol[ReturnType])`.

Answer (score 6):

[This answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42486054/10784842) suggests [`typing.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence).
This type supports both `__getitem__` and `__len__`.

Given that it is currently deprecated, however, I suppose it would be better to use [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence).

As mentioned by the author later on in the comments, however, he/she actually needs something with `__delitem__` too, in which case [`collections.abc.MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence) may be the most appropriate (it is also mentioned by @Yuval in the comments). It supports all of `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`, `__len__`, and `insert`.

An example usage of the final type (adapted from [the reference answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42486054/10784842)):

```
from collections.abc import MutableSequence

def foo(bar: MutableSequence[Any]):
    # bar is a mutable sequence of any objects
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind: `Sequence` implies that there is an order to keys, i.e. values can be accessed using keys in `range(len(var))`. If the keys are not such, `Mapping` is more suitable.

Comment: Interesting. Would [`collections.abc.MutableMapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableMapping) be more appropriate then? You do mention needing to have `__delitem__` (I must have misread Yuval when I said he mentioned `MutableSequence` when he actually said `MutableMapping`)

Comment: If you need modify the container than yes `MutableMapping` is better.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the closest we can get is:

```
Mapping[int, Any]
```

Although it's not quite what I wanted, it's close enough.

Comment: Why isn't this enough? Can you show the usage of the class?

Comment: I guess it does work for the question stated, but I later realised I also need the type to support `__delitem__` method, which is not provided by `Mapping`. I didn't know that `__getitem__` and `__delitem__` need to be specified separately.

Comment: @Rizhiy you can use MutableMapping