# How to type a function that can take a list or tuple of a list or tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples, type-hinting, mypy

I'm trying to define a function that can take containers of containers of objects, and I don't care if the containers are Tuples or Lists.

(I know I could go through the hassle of implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48314895), but I don't want to, and I'm still not sure if that would solve my problem.)

So, I have the following code:

```py
from typing import Any, Union, List, Tuple

# (list or tuple) of Any
AnyBucket = Union[List[Any], Tuple[Any, ...]]
# should be (list or tuple) of (lists or tuples) of Any
AnyBuckets = Union[List[AnyBucket], Tuple[AnyBucket, ...]]

def takes_any_buckets(inpt: AnyBuckets) -> None:
    print(inpt[0][0])

input_value: List[List[Any]] = [[1], [2]]

# Argument 1 to "takes_any_buckets" has incompatible type "List[List[Any]]";
# expected "Union[List[Union[List[Any], Tuple[Any, ...]]], Tuple[Union[List[Any], Tuple[Any, ...]], ...]]"
takes_any_buckets(input_value)
```

I have two questions:

1. Why is Mypy throwing an error for this?
2. What can I do to get the functionality (not getting a Mypy error) that I want?

(I don't want to just disable the error with `# type: ignore`, I want to define a type that will work.)

My guess for (1) is that it has something to do with `List`s being [invariant](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html), but with this complex of an example, I can't figure out how.

I have no ideas for (2) other than possibly implementing the previously mentioned hassle, which would allow me to get rid of the `Union`s, which I suspect may be part of the problem.

Comment: If you're fine with either `tuple` or `list`, is there a reason not to just accept `typing.Sequence` (that covers both) or `typing.Container` (a little broader, accepts non-indexable types like `set`)?

Comment: Thank you; I just discovered Sequence (which works for my case) on my own in the past couple minutes. If you write it as an answer for question (2) I'll accept for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It does indeed have to do with lists being invariant. The current version of Mypy will tell you this; if you run your code in the current version, you get the following notes, along with the error:

```
main.py:14: note: "List" is invariant -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance
main.py:14: note: Consider using "Sequence" instead, which is covariant
```

What it means for lists to be invariant is that a list of things of type `A` is a sub-type of a list of things of type `B` if and only if `A` is equal to `B`. This means that *even when A is a subtype of `B`*, `List[A]` is not a subtype of `List[B]`. (See here, both for an explanation of invariance and why mypy treats lists as invariant: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types).

So `List[List[Any]]` is not a subtype of `List[AnyBucket]`, even though `List[Any]` is a subtype of `AnyBucket`, so `input_value` does not have a type compatible with `AnyBuckets`. Hence the error.

2. As Mypy and ShadowRanger both recommend above, you should probably use `Sequence`, a covariant type that covers iterables that can be indexed into (to a first approximation -- there are some other things that need to be true of a collection for it to be a sequence). You'll need to import it from collections.abc; see here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence

I say "probably" because it depends on exactly what the function you want to type does with the collection. If, for instance, all you do is iterate through the collection (once), then you want to use `Iterable`, a more generic type.

An advantage of using something like `Sequence` is that if there are any other types of objects floating around out there -- perhaps user defined ones -- that can do the job you want, they will be valid inputs to your function (as long as they have been registered as `Sequences`). In general, it's nice if you can use [structural typing](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html), which is the static-typing version equivalent of [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), which is the Python Way.