How to annotate different iterable types with same items' type?
For example:
How to set the argument type to: list, which contains ints and floats, or tuple, which contains ints and floats?
tried:
from typing import List, Tuple, Union

def some(arg: Union[List, Tuple][int, float]): ...

Raises
TypeError: typing.Union[typing.List, typing.Tuple] is not a generic class

The general question is for any iterables' types' combinations and any content types.

What specifically does the list or the tuple contain? Does the list contain exactly two items, the first one must an int and the second a float? And the same question if it's a tuple?

List[int|float] | Tuple[int|float]?

It was suggested in the Staging Ground that this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/42486006/238704, but I don't think that is quite right, though there are similarities.

It would be nice to have higher-kinded type variables, letting you do something like def some[F: (list, tuple), T](arg: F[T]): ... The issue has been raised before (e.g, https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/6066), but I don't know if there is any plan for increased support.

in this specific case you should probably use typing.Sequence[int | float], although depending on what some does (i.e., does it actually use list specifi methods) you may not be able to

Since your function accepts a tuple, I assume you don't need to modify arg. Therefore, I will skip possible solutions with MutableSequence.
Python 3.10+
Use collections.abc.Iterable or collections.abc.Sequence:
from collections.abc import Iterable, Sequence


def some_iterable(arg: Iterable[int | float]):
    ...


def some_sequence(arg: Sequence[int | float]):
    ...

Python 3.9
In Python 3.9, you have to use typing.Union:
from collections.abc import Iterable, Sequence
from typing import Union


def some_iterable(arg: Iterable[Union[int, float]]):
    ...


def some_sequence(arg: Sequence[Union[int, float]]):
    ...

before Python 3.9
Use typing.Iterable or typing.Sequence in combination with typing.Union:
from typing import Iterable, Sequence, Union


def some_iterable(arg: Iterable[Union[int, float]]):
    ...


def some_sequence(arg: Sequence[Union[int, float]]):
    ...

Iterable vs Sequence
If you are unsure wether to use Iterable or Sequence, consider which operations you need to do with arg. I highly recommend this overview to see which abstract base class supports which operations.
For example, if you need to do arg[0], use Sequence. This means arg can also be a bytes or even a range object.
If you don't need to index arg, but you need len(arg), use Collection. Here, arg can also be a set.
If you just need to loop over arg, use Iterable. Now you can also pass generator expressions or other iterators as returned by map or itertools functions.
